# Is there a way to adjust the Simics memory window display granularity?

Tags: simics

I would like to display memory in 32 bit chunks with the little endianness resolved in the "Debug -> Memory Contents" UI window, instead of only 8-bit chunks. Is this possible?

(I know I can do this via x in the CLI, but in some situations I prefer to just easily have a self-updating GUI view of things.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am quite certain that such a feature is not available.